# Data scaling before PCA: how to deal with categorical values?

Tags: categorical-data, pca, normalization, feature-scaling

I have to apply PCA on a dataset, which contains both numerical and categorical values. In the preprocessing phase, I converted all the categorical values in numerical, so that the software can deal with them (basically I created dummy variables). Now, in order to apply PCA I have to scale the data matrix such that I have mean equal to 0. 
My question is: does it make sense to normalize also the categorical values (which now are numbers, but they are actually categorical values)? I think it doesn't, but in that case how do I proceed? I do the PCA without scaling these variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can not use PCA, or at least it is not recommended, for mixed data. It is best to use [Factor analysis of mixed data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis_of_mixed_data). You are lucky that [Prince](https://github.com/MaxHalford/prince) is a Python package that covers all data scenarios, borrowing from its explanation:

> - All your variables are numeric: use principal component analysis (prince.PCA)
> - You have a contingency table: use correspondence analysis (prince.CA)
> - You have more than 2 variables and they are all categorical: use multiple correspondence analysis (prince.MCA)
> - You have groups of categorical or numerical variables: use multiple factor analysis (prince.MFA)
> - You have both categorical and numerical variables: use factor analysis of mixed data (prince.FAMD)

Check also this [question/answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont) in stats.stackexchange or discussion in [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Should_I_use_PCA_with_categorical_data).